# csv export using displaytag gives html tags in the output file

Tags: csv, displaytag

We are trying to export the data from jsp to csv file using displaytag library. But we are getting all html related tags in the csv file when opened. Following changes we have made in our application for this.
- imported displaytag libraries (displaytag and displaytag-export-poi 1.1 version)
- made changes to the jsp tags to use displaytags (simple displaytable and displaycolumn tags)
- modified web.xml to use ResponseOverrrideFilter and put it on top of other filters
- have created displaytag.properties file to define csv related properties

We have checked most of the examples given on net for this export to csv functionality and still not able to resolve this problem. When the file gets downloaded it simply displays all html related tags (which are used by displaytag library internally i guess).

Please can someone help us resolve this issue. Has anyone faced such kind of problem before?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please post your .properties and the html/jsp portion where you used the display tag. and check the dependency here http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/dependencies.html