# Displaytag Export Excel Issue - HTML Code inside the output excel file

Tags: java, excel, jsp, displaytag

Some one has had the same problem before here in SO, but unfortunately no answer for that.

[csv export using displaytag gives html tags in the output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649171/csv-export-using-displaytag-gives-html-tags-in-the-output-file)

Am having the same problem here.

I have a table. I use display tag for exporting it in to Excel. It works fine.

### Column 1  | Column 2 | Column 3 | Group |

A1    |       B1    |    C1   |     G1 
A2    |        B2    |     C2   |   G2
A3    |        B3    |     C3   |   G1
A4    |        B4    |     C4   |   G2

Now, I have a feature called , group by , where it groups by a specific columns. The tables would change as

### Column 1  | Column 2 | Column 3 | Group |

G1
A1    |       B1    |    C1   |     G1 
A3    |        B3    |     C3   |   G1 
G2
A2    |        B2    |     C2   |   G2
A4    |        B4    |     C4   |   G2

If I try to export this, am getting HTML tags `tr` and `td` inside the output excel file.
Is it a bug?? or am I missing anything!!

Comment: Hi, Do you have solution for this. Even i too have same issue but here I have hyperlink <a
href="/ABCD/rse/getData.action?idDtl=1>1212121</a>. Hyperlink as it is showing in exported pdf/excel file.

Comment: This question was 5 years old and my problem happened to be a bug. But the sad thing is this technology is very much outdated as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in TableDecorator. Unfortunately, even the demo page does not have a case like this!!!